# fwrite() succeeded after fclose()

Tags: c, fwrite, fclose

I've encountered a strange behavior that is `fwrite()`succeeds after I close the stream with `fclose()` but the file is not overwritten as `fflush()` fails.

My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
   if(!file) perror("Cannot open the file.\n");

    char text[] = "1234567";

    fclose(file);

    int count_of_written_objects = fwrite(text, sizeof(text),1, file);
    printf("Count of written objects into the file: %d \n", count_of_written_objects);

    if(count_of_written_objects != 1) perror("Not expected count of objects was written.\n");

    int success = fflush(file);
    printf("Variable success: %d \n", success);                                                                                                                
    if(success == EOF) perror("Flush did not succeed. \n");

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
Count of written objects into the file: 1 
Variable success: -1 
Flush did not succeed. 
: Bad file descriptor
```

How can `fwrite()` succeed when the stream is closed? Can `fwrite()` write on the closed stream? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: What is this: `if(close(errno = EBADF))` for?

Comment: It presumably _should_ be `if( errno == EBADF )...`.  What it currently does is assign `EBADF` to `errno` and then try to close the file-handle with whatever number `EBADF` is (`9`?).  Since this probably isn't open, `close()` is returning an error-state and printing the message.

Comment: That was an error in the code, I've repaired it and updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure about your code, because if `!file` is true then file should equals to `NULL` and then `fwrite()` should crash because `NULL` is not a valid stream. Except if your system is doing weird things with a NULL stream. What is your system ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès After calling `fclose()` the pointer `file` won't be set to `NULL`, so `fwrite()` gets a valid memory address. I have a Debian-based system.

Comment: The test is true, then file is false, and the sole possible value for it is NULL (0). fclose won't change file's value. So in your code, when fwrite is called, file is NULL.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Maybe you are misreading the source because of the inappropriate indentation. The `if (!file)` statement holds only the call to `perror` (which is oddly placed on the same line).

Comment: You're right I misread...

Comment: I tried on two systems: on osx the answer is the one you expect : 0, on my Ubuntu it says : 1 but nothing is written. What I can say is that Linux kernel and libraries sometimes do strange things, most of them are either to obtain performance or to prevent crashs even if the code is logically false. That is crazy for your example because you may thing that something has been written which is not the case.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: In both cases this is caused by a programmer mistake (calling `fwrite` after `fclose`), so trying to validate that case in an inherently unsafe language such as C isn't crucial.

Comment: I don't agree with this. It is crucial to know that your output is correct or not, whatever is the level of safety of your language. I am currently digging into libc sources to understand what's happening...

Comment: On OSX the fwrite call sets errno to EBADF which is correct. Don't understand why it is not the same on Linux.

Comment: `errno` is set by the system call `write`, not by the `fwrite` library function. Whether `write` gets called is a matter of the buffering that `fwrite` does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54804/discussion-between-jean-baptiste-yunes-and-blagovest-buyukliev).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attempting to do any operations on a file after it has been closed, you are dealing with undefined behaviour.

The library implementer assumes that it is the responsibility of the caller to issue the calls in a certain order, hence the library may or may not try to validate the cases where that isn't true. Validation for such cases is ignored mostly for performance and reducing the code size.

The same thing will happen if you attempt to write to a memory location that has been previously `free`'d. Even though it may seem as if everything works correctly, you are invoking undefined behaviour.

Technically speaking, in the particular case it shouldn't be possible for the write to succeed, because the library function `fclose` will most probably call the `close` system call on the underlying descriptor, and any subsequent `write` system calls to that descriptor (eventually invoked by `fwrite`) should fail because it will be rejected by the kernel.

Comment: No, writing to a closed file is not an undefined behaviour, it is an error, it should not succeed!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: source?

Comment: Because this is the semantic of open/closed files! To write you need to open first, and if you close the handler should be unavailable for.

Comment: You're right @blagovest, this is exactly what happens with the GNU libc. fwrite just does nothing but behave just like everything was ok. This is astonishing to me, but ok we learn every day, sometimes the hard way!

Comment: I've encountered a similar behaviour using fwrite on a stream opened with "rb" with msvc! Despite no bytes were written it returned with the correct amount of bytes i intended to write. I was expecting fwrite to return 0 and setting ferror appropriately.