# Using _fwrite_nolock() with FILE* of already closed file returns 0 and continue execution, but using fwrite() in same case results in run time error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017

I was looking into the application, where it logs some events by writing specific information into the log file. The application ( which is built using multi threaded run time libraries, but doesn't use multithreading )  was using _fwrite_nolock() call to  write to the log, which was recently replaced by fwrite() function. As the result of this change, the error was found, that at some earlier point of execution, there is a call to fclose() function used the same FILE* pointer, used by fwrite() function later( and not re-setting the pointer to the NULL ), resulting in the run time error. This is expected, as the file was closed already, but it doesn't happened with the call of _fwrite_nolock(), which only returns zero as the return code and continue execution. I couldn't find explanation for such behavior. Hope someone can do it. Thanks.

Comment: Using a pointer after free is undefined behavior and can do anything, including the appearance of working as intended.

Comment: I'm not sure what the Standard says about calling `fwrite()` on a FILE* that has already been closed with `fclose()`? There's a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954102/fwrite-succeeded-after-fclose

Comment: The debug build of fwrite() has very helpful asserts that assist  programmers in diagnosing bugs in their code.  Such as trying to write to a closed file.  Notably a bug that is exploitable, handle recycle attacks are extremely nasty.  No doubt the previous programmer saw that assert as well, instead of fixing that bug they decided to shoot the messenger.

Comment: Thanks, @Adrian. I hope to see some comments if this can be in some way related to not using locking, comparing to do it with fwrite call.