# Send files over UART

Tags: python, c, embedded-linux, uart, termios

I am transferring 6 different files from my Windows PC to BeagleBone over UART communication. I have written receiving (BeagleBone) side C code to receive and store 6 files at the "/home/debian/NEW" location.

Also, I have written a script to send 6 files from PC to BeagleBone.

1. BeagleBone side C code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UART_PORT "/dev/ttyS1"
#define BAUD_RATE B9600
#define UART_BUFFER_SIZE 8192

enum State {
    IDLE,
    FILENAME,
    DATA
};

char readByte(int uart_fd) {
    char byte;
    ssize_t bytesRead = read(uart_fd, &byte, 1);

    if (bytesRead < 0) {
        perror("Error reading from UART");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return byte;
}

void receiveAndStoreFilesOverUART(const char *folderPath) {
    int uart_fd = open(UART_PORT, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    struct termios uart_config;

    if (uart_fd < 0) {
        perror("Error opening UART port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Configure UART settings
    if (tcgetattr(uart_fd, &uart_config) < 0) {
        perror("Error getting UART configuration");
        close(uart_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cfsetispeed(&uart_config, BAUD_RATE);
    cfsetospeed(&uart_config, BAUD_RATE);
    uart_config.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    uart_config.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    uart_config.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    uart_config.c_cflag |= CS8;
    uart_config.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    uart_config.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    uart_config.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    uart_config.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    uart_config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    if (tcsetattr(uart_fd, TCSANOW, &uart_config) < 0) {
        perror("Error setting UART configuration");
        close(uart_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    enum State state = IDLE;
    int finished = 0;
    char filenameBuffer[256];
    FILE *file = NULL;

    while (!finished) {
        char byte = readByte(uart_fd);

        switch (state) {
            case IDLE:
                if (byte == 0x01) {
                    state = FILENAME;
                    filenameBuffer[0] = '\0'; // Reset the filename buffer
                    printf("Entering FILENAME state\n");
                } else if (byte == 0x04) {
                    finished = 1;
                    printf("Entering IDLE state\n");
                }
                break;

            case FILENAME:
                if (byte == 0x02) {
                    state = DATA;
                    printf("Entering DATA state\n");
                } else if (byte == 0x04) {
                    finished = 1;
                    printf("Entering IDLE state\n");
                } else {
                    strncat(filenameBuffer, &byte, 1);
                }
                break;

            case DATA:
                if (byte == 0x03) {
                    if (file != NULL) {
                        fclose(file);
                        printf("File closed\n");
                        state = IDLE;
                    }
                } else if (byte == 0x04) {
                    if (file != NULL) {
                        fclose(file);
                        printf("File closed\n");
                    }
                    finished = 1;
                } else {
                    if (file == NULL) {
                        // Open the file for writing if not already open
                        snprintf(filenameBuffer, sizeof(filenameBuffer), "%s/%s", folderPath, filenameBuffer);
                        file = fopen(filenameBuffer, "wb");
                        if (file == NULL) {
                            perror("Error opening file");
                            finished = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (file != NULL) {
                        fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, file);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    close(uart_fd);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *storageFolderPath = "/home/debian/NEW";
    receiveAndStoreFilesOverUART(storageFolderPath);
    printf("Finished receiving\n");
    return 0;
}
```

2. Windows (Transmitting) side Python code

```python
import serial
import time

def send_file(serial_port, file_name):
    try:
        # Send start marker (0x01)
        serial_port.write(bytes([0x01]))

        # Send filename
        serial_port.write(file_name.encode())

        # Send filename marker (0x02)
        serial_port.write(bytes([0x02]))

        # Open the file for reading
        with open(f"C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/DRS_Database/{file_name}", "rb") as file:
            # Send file data marker (0x03)
            serial_port.write(bytes([0x03]))

            # Send file data
            file_data = file.read()
            serial_port.write(file_data)

        print(f"{file_name} sent successfully.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File {file_name} not found.")

def send_files(serial_port, filenames):
    for file_name in filenames:
        send_file(serial_port, file_name)
        time.sleep(1)  # Add a delay to allow time for the BeagleBone to process the data

    # Send finish marker (0x04) after all files are sent
    serial_port.write(bytes([0x04]))

# Open the serial port for communication
ser = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600)  # COM port and baud rate

# List of file names to send
file_names = ["DIA_ID.TXT", "OP_REC.TXT", "DIA_REC.TXT", "PAT_REC.TXT", "JAR_REC.TXT", "PRO_REC.TXT"]

# Send files
send_files(ser, file_names)

# Close the serial port
ser.close()`
```

All file data is stored in one folder: /home/debian/NEW. No separate files are stored.

The content of files that I send from my Windows PC using a Python script is stored in a folder. It does not generate separate files.

Comment: "*It does not generate separate files.*" - Your C code compiles cleanly, but you seem to have done little or no debugging. The **snprintf()** statement has a destination buffer that is also the 2nd source buffer!  Also your termios setup is incomplete, but may not give you any problems right now. Your scheme is not robust, and will break if these magic numbers appear in the files.  Your C code is very inefficient by reading only one byte at a time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392470/how-to-handle-buffering-serial-data/54394770#54394770

Comment: You seem to do a decent job of checking the return code from most syscalls (although some of that code bears a strong resemblance to code that I've written/posted). But you missed checking one salient syscall that could help solve your (primary) bug. Unfortunately your mistake will not be detected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954102/fwrite-succeeded-after-fclose

Comment: Why can't you enable SLIP or PPP over UART and use some high level protocols like [t]ftp?

Comment: In the olden days, Kermit was used to send files over serial lines between disparate systems.

Comment: @MarkRansom or Zmodem :-)